# Javascript event targeting a list item but not it's elements

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, event-handling, dom-events

I have this dom and JS:

```js
var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInp');
var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggest");
suggestions.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var pressed = evt.target.textContent;
  searchInput.value = pressed;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="search" id="searchInp">
<ul id="suggest">
  <li>example<span>something</span></li>
  <li>test sentence</li>
  <li><span>example</span> car</li>
</ul>
```

The suggestions list is dynamically updated based in the input, and I'm trying to make get the list item `textContent` with the span if it's there. 
The current code gets the whole list content if I press on the list item, or the span inside the list item, or the whole list depending on where you press. These are snippets from a larger document.

Please no jQuery answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `evt.target` if it is the ul element itself, if so ignore the click and just do a `return`.

Otherwise check if it is an li element, if not use either [Element#closest(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) or the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill) to go up the node tree til you reach the list item

```
suggestions.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var listItem = null;
  if (evt.target == suggestions) {
    //they clicked somewhere on the UL itself and not a child element.
    return;
  } else if (!(evt.target instanceof HTMLLIElement)) {
    //They clicked some other child element
    //Find the closest parent list item that is direct child of #suggest
    listItem = evt.target.closest('#suggest > li');
  } else {
    listItem = evt.target;
  }
  searchInput.value = listItem.textContent;
}, false);
```

Demo

```js
var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInp');
var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggest");

suggestions.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var listItem = null;
  if (evt.target == suggestions) {
    return;
  } else if (!(evt.target instanceof HTMLLIElement)) {
    listItem = evt.target.closest('#suggest > li');
  } else {
    listItem = evt.target;
  }
  searchInput.value = listItem.textContent;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="search" id="searchInp">
<ul id="suggest">
  <li>example<span>something</span></li>
  <li>test sentence</li>
  <li><span>example</span> car</li>
</ul>
```